# Unpacking a laptop touchpad to clean the keys

Tags: laptop, touchpad, cleaning, maintenance

How can I get to and remove the touchpad buttons on my laptop in order to try and clean them and the area around the buttons?

I have an Acer laptop and I think I have a hardware problem where something is wrong with the laptop mouse keys.

I've found some tips/pictures about how to remove/replace the keyboard, but nothing about the touchpad buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to disassemble the entire laptop to get at that.

- The first step is removing the bezel above the keyboard.
- Then remove all screws from the bottom of the laptop.
- Then carefully pry the bottom panel off.
- The touchpad should be exposed.

[Here is a thorough video on disassembling an Acer laptop](http://www.insidemylaptop.com/category/1-acer-laptops/)